# Throwing Exceptions when implementing methods

Tags: java

I am given an interface with comments on how the methods should be implemented in java.

```
One interface method with the comments
<p> If newX is not null, then the method setX changes it's x so that it will be newX. 
If newX is null, then setX throws an IllegalArgumentException without changing anything.

public void setX(String newX) throws IllegalArgumentException


My implementation

public void setX(String newX) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if(newX == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("newX may not be null");
    if(newX != null)
        x = newX;
}
```

Is this how you would throw an exception? Also, seeing how it would throw an exception when it's null, can I just remove the second if statement where it checks if newX isn't null? Any improvements on this would be appreciated as well.

Comment: It should be newX.setX(x) instead of x = newX

Comment: Yes you can remove the `if(newX != null)`, it's guaranteed at that point to be non-null.

Comment: @alainlompo ?? `newX` is a `String`, which doesn't have a `setX` method... your suggestion would imply setting the _parameter_ to `x`. How exactly is `x = newX;` wrong?

Comment: right, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, and you're right that you can remove the second `if` statement; if the program reaches the third line of your method, then `newX` is certainly not `null`.

You also don't need the `throws` declaration, because `IllegalArgumentException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`. `try`/`catch` blocks and `throws` declarations are only required by the compiler if the code throws an exception that *isn't* a subclass of `RuntimeException`.

It's a very common pattern in Java for handling illegal arguments:

```
public returnType method(arguments) {
    if (an argument is invalid)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Message");

    // At this point, you can assume arguments are valid
    // ... the rest of the method ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your implementation would work fine, however if you are throwing the IllegalArgument in the if statement, you do not need to repeat this in the method deceleration.

i.e. your could write:

```
public void setX(String newX)
{
    if(newX == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("newX may not be null");
    if(newX != null)
        x = newX;
}
```

Typically, you would use 'throws IllegalArgumentException' in the method declaration when you have an unhandled exception in your own code.

For example, your method may use the line Thread.sleep(1000) which thrown an Interrupt Exception, if you didn't want your method to handle this, you could pass it on to where the method was originally called:

```
public void run() throws InterruptedException {

    // code
    Thread.sleep(1);
}
```

instead of

```
public void run() {

try {
    Thread.sleep(1); // delay by 100ms
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, the code whether run() was called will need to handle the Exception. Hopefully that clears up some understanding, you can do one or the other, but it is not needed that you do both.